# How do I write a table to file using python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a neat little table using `tabulate`:

```
from tabulate import tabulate
outputList = dictOfOutputs.items()
table = outputList
print tabulate(table)
```

How do I print this to a text file?

Comment: `fileobj.write(tabulate(table))`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just write it how you normally would write a string to a file:

```
with open('table.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(tabulate(table))
```

Comment: Or better, `with open('table.txt', 'w') as f: f.write(tabulate(table))`, or even `open('table.txt', 'w').write(tabulate(table))`,

Answer (score 1):

The `tabulate()` function returns a string; just write it to a file:

```
with open('filename.txt', 'w') as outputfile:
    outputfile.write(tabulate(table))
```

You can always make `print` output to a file instead of `sys.stdout` by using `>>` redirection:

```
with open('filename.txt', 'w') as outputfile:
    print >> outputfile, tabulate(table)
```

or by using the [`print()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print) (put `from __future__ import print_function` at the top of your module if you are using Python 2):

```
from __future__ import print_function

with open('filename.txt', 'w') as outputfile:
    print(tabulate(table), file=outputfile)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x=int(input('enter the number: '))
y=int(input('enter the number to which you want to write the table'))
# empty list to store the table
L=[]
#Table function
def table(m):
    for i in range (0,y+1):
        L.append(str((f'{m}x{i}={m*i}\n')))
table(x) 
print(L)
f=open('table.txt','w')
f.writelines(L)
f.close()
```